# Equivalent cross-variation formula in terms of Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I'd like to show that

$$\langle I^M(X),I^N(Y)\rangle_t=\int_0^t X_uY_u\,d\langle M,N\rangle_u\text{ holds for all } t\ge0,\ P-a.s.$$
is equivalent to

$$E[(I_t^M(X)-I_s^M(X))(I_t^N(Y)-I_s^N(Y))|\mathcal F_s]=E\biggr[\int_s^t X_uY_u\,d\langle M,N\rangle_u|\mathcal F_s\biggr]\text{ holds for all }0\le s<t<\infty,\ P-a.s.$$

$M,N$ are continuous square integrable martingales, and $X,Y$ are progressively measurable processes for which the stochastic integrals $I^M(X)=\int_0^t X_s\,dM_s$ and $I^N(Y)=\int_0^t Y_s\,dN_s$ are defined (Definition 3.2.9 in Karatzas and Shreve's *Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus*, the text this question comes from).

It is easy to see that the former implies the latter, by noting that if $A,B$ are square integrable martingales and $0<t\le u<v$, $E[(A_v-A_u)(B_v-B_u)|\mathcal F_t]=E[\langle A,B\rangle_v-\langle A,B\rangle_u|\mathcal F_t].$ I'm having trouble seeing the other direction.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.